# Solving $\tan^{-1}(2i)$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

I'm not sure how to find the inverse tan of a complex number, since it's multivalued. So this is what I did:
$$\tan ^{-1}(2i) = z\\2i = \tan z = \tan(x+iy) \\ \tan(x+iy) = \frac{\tan x + i\tanh y}{1 - i\tan x \tanh y} = 2i \\  \tan x + i\tanh y = 2i + 2 \tan x \tanh y \\ \tan x (1-2\tanh y) + i(\tanh y - 2) = 0$$
So this means (equating imaginary and real parts), that $\tanh y = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\tanh y = 2$ simultaneously....
Not sure where I went wrong here..

Comment: $\tan x(1-2\tanh y)=0$ does **not** imply $\tanh y=1/2$.

Comment: Even before the blunder mentioned by @LordSharktheUnknown, note that when you decompose $\tan(x+iy)$, you implicitely assume that $\tan x$ and $\tanh y$ both exist. As regards $y$, this is not a problem since $\tanh y$ exists for every real $y$, but on the side of $x$, doing so, you eliminate every $x$ in $\pi/2+\pi\mathbb Z$...a set which happens to contain the real part of every solution of the equation. :-(

Comment: To solve this more simply, note that $$\tan z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{i(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})}=-i\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{e^{2iz}+1}$$ solve $\tan(z)=2i$ for $e^{2iz}$ using the RHS, and finally deduce the set of solutions $z$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Is it because $\tan x$ can also be $0$ instead? I thought that even so, $\tanh y = 1/2$ would also include a solution

Comment: @Did Thank you that's much easier, and I didn't realise I was automatically discarding every solution to the equation so thanks for that as well

Comment: @Natash1 You might want to post an answer yourself, since your question, so far, only attracted a wrong answer and an incomplete one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By @Did's recommendation and also hint:

$$\tan z = 2i \\ \frac{(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})/2i}{(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2} = 2i \\ e^{iz} - e^{-iz} = -2e^{iz} - 2e^{-iz} \\ 3e^{2iz} + 1 = 0 \\ e^{2iz} = -\frac{1}{3} \\ 2iz = \ln(\frac{1}{3}) + i\pi \bmod{ 2\pi i} \\ z = \frac\pi2+i\,\frac{\ln3}2\bmod{\pi}.$$